# How to calculate growth rate from a semi-log plot?

Tags: logarithm, growth-model

In the following plot, if we model the population growth as a linear function of time, what would be a good estimate of the linear growth rate?

[image]

I don't know if it's the slope or the intercept!

Answer (score 2):

It's not a linear growth rate; bacterial growth is an exponential function of time, whether you plot it on a linear or log scale (using a log scale does have some nice variance stabilising properties, though). And yes, the slope of the line above is the (exponential) growth rate. The intercept just tells you about the starting density.

Comment: isn't the growth rate the value of y in the x=1?

Comment: @Ahmad No, the y-values are just cell densities. The growth rate is the *rate of change of density over time*, which is the slope of the line.